# Clearing array values for new entries

Tags: c#

My question is how can I re-write this code so that the array will clear itself if the user dedcides to enter more bowling scores?

```
while (!userIsDone)// loop will continue as long as the userIsDone = false
            {
                Console.Write("\nWould you like to process another set of bowling scores?");// prompt user to input Y or N to quit or to
                Console.WriteLine("\nPress 'Y' to process another set or 'N' to exit the program");// input new bowling scores
                string userInput = Console.ReadLine();// reads the user input to check against if/else below


                if (userInput == "N")// if userInput is literal N the program will exectute this block
                {
                    userIsDone = true;//exits program by setting userIsDone to true
                }
                else if (userInput == "Y")//if the user inputs a literal Y this block will execute
                {
                    Console.Clear();// clears the console
                    break;// jumps out of the loop and returns to the prompt to input scores
                }
                else
                {
                    // left blank to end the if and return to beginning of while because userInput was not Y or N  
                }


            }//end while
            //end do while
        } while (!userIsDone);// continues to loop until userIsDone is true                 

    }
}
```

}

Edit: Sorry for not putting what I have done so far in, I've been tinkering with Array.Clear, but I want to know if there is another way to clear it without using built in methods.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Maybe take a look at ["How do I ask good Questions"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and show that you’ve already put some effort into solving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods:

`Array.Clear` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear(v=vs.110).aspx)), which will set all the array elements to their default value.

You could write your own version of this method:

```
void ClearArray<T>(T[] array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        array[i] = default(T);
}
```

Though realistically, I don't see any value in using that as opposed to the pre-existing one. You could also just make a *new* array; though this is pretty inefficient as you have to allocate memory for the new array, and the old one is left in memory until the garbage collector cleans it up.

```
scores = new int[10];
```

Each approach gets you to the same place, but I would just use `Array.Clear`.